# easy question about managing static content in django

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates

I have a simple website in django where the content is static. Where i use templates like "AboutUs.html" ,"OurServices.html" or "contact.html".. now i want to use the django admin so anyone could change the content for those pages using a WYSIWYG editor (cause the people who will change this dont know html).. i wanted to create a class called StaticContent, something like:

```
class StaticContent(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField("content")
```

then i taught that maybe there's something in django that can do that, but i couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Do you know if django has some module or something to manage this static content in the admin?

Thxs in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is the flatpages app that is bundled with Django

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/flatpages/